# Create a complete hoogle database for a cabal project with all dependencies included

Tags: haskell, documentation, cabal, haddock, hoogle

I am trying to generate a hoogle database for a cabal project. I would like to have the documentation for dependencies too.

I tried different approaches but in all the cases my hoogle database is incomplete (some dependencies are missing). My constraints:

- ghc-8.10.7
- cabal-3.10.1.0
- haddock-2.24.2

I have different projects inside my `cabal.project` file.

Things I tried:

#### Regular cabal

```bash
cabal haddock all --haddock-hoogle --haddock-html --keep-going --haddock-quickjump
```

[It seems](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/Cabal-v3.10.1.0/cabal-install/src/Distribution/Client/CmdHaddock.hs#L64-L65) that currently we cannot do that.

Anyway, I’m a bit puzzled here because in my project I had some dependencies under a `source-repository-package` stanza with some broken haddock I had to fix those in order to run `cabal haddock` successfully - I am wondering whether that comment is outdated or am I not understanding something here. Any idea?
In any case, I can get the databases for the project packages but not for the dependencies.

### Cabal haddock-project

I tried to use this by manually installing a more recent version of haddock, basically following [coot's guide](https://coot.me/posts/cabal-haddock-project.html) but the tool is actually checking GHC versions: here is the error message I have:

```
    
    The GHC version is 8.10.7 but haddock is using GHC version 9.4.8
```

#### cabal-hoogle

I found this [cabal-hoogle](https://github.com/kokobd/cabal-hoogle). The tool is simple and does not have many flags so I just followed the documentation and I managed to create a database but some dependencies are missing (in fact many of them), anyway this was the best solution I found so far.

`cabal-hoogle` is using cabal and hoogle APIs directly so I think I will start digging into it if I don’t find better solutions.

---

## Questions

Do you see anything wrong in what I tried to do and/or do you have any advice on how to proceed on this?

With the knowledge I have, I think my next step would be start digging into cabal/cabal-hoogle to better understand what's going on, do you have any other approach to suggest?